# Change root in angular with asp.net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular6

I want to change root in my application from `angular-cli.json` or `startup.cs`, when I debug the home page always is `index.html` in folder " wwwroot ".
I'am using .net core 1.1.

[image]

This is my code in `angular-cli.json`:

```json
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "wwwroot",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
```

What would be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try and use the following:

**`startup.cs`**:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "your/folder/path";
        });
    }
```

*description*:

> Gets or sets the path, relative to the application root, of the
>   directory in which the physical files are located.
>
> If the specified directory does not exist, then the
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.SpaStaticFilesExtensions.UseSpaStaticFiles(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder)
>   middleware will not serve any static files

Comment: I did that but there is an exception " iservicecollection does not contain a definition for addspastaticfiles ",so i have installed " Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices -Version 1.1.1 " and put using ... in the top of startup.cs file , also i have .csproj file two packages ( <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" /> )    but the same exception appear !!